# What is the best way to return multiple values from a WCF service

Tags: wcf, web-services

What is the best way to return multiple values from a WCF service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, this *must* be a duplicate.

Just create a class with properties for the values. Make the class a [DataContract] and the properties [DataMember]. Return an isntance of that class. Works on all clients.

Answer (score 2):

In a separate object, e.g.:

```
public class DTO
{
   public string Data1 { get; set;}
   public string Data2 { get; set;}
}
```

and you then return an instance of DTO from the method.

Comment: You don't have to. You can also create a service contract and define it as a known type on that service, place the DTO classes in a separate assembly and reference it both in client and service

Answer (score 1):

Either wrap them in a separate class that will be decorated with [DataContract] and return it from your method or use [out parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx(VS.80).aspx) in your method call.